# AppEngine Datastore Admin: cannot backup to cloudstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backup, google-cloud-storage, datastore-admin

I am trying to backup some entities from my Java app to cloudstore via the Datastore Admin and running into some issues.

I enabled Datastore Admin and added the google service account id of my app (my_app_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) to the cloud storage bucket "team" as a developer, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview#Prerequisites) (5.e).

I see the invitation as "pending" on the bucket "team" (screenshot of the [app-engine dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eIIt.png)) but **I have no idea how to accept the invitation** or if this is automatic and I just have to wait.

When I try to backup to my cloudstore bucket [`gs/my_bucket/my_folder`] I get `Bucket "my_bucket" is not accessible` (same error I get if I try random bucket names).

I am using the same account (owner on everything) to do all the above.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**:

I was creating the project via the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console), which was causing (apparently a bug) my project to be created as an app-engine app, so whenever I clicked on 'team' from the Google APIs console I was redirected to the AppEngine dashboard permission tab.

If I create the project from the Google APIs console then everything works ok, and I am able to add permissions without being redirected to an AppEngine dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The problem here seems to be that there strange behaviour when creating a API Project from http://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage rather than in the API console.

Previous answer:

My reading of the 5.e you link to is that you're supposed to add the service account name of your app to the *API project* (in the Google API Console) not the App Engine project. I don't think it should be a developer of your App Engine app.

That is, you've added your App Engine app as a developer to your App Engine app. Instead, you want to add it as a member of your API project (which includes the cloud storage access).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I added my AppEngine app as a developer of the API project. When you click on "team" on the API project it brings you to the permissions tab of an AppEngine dashboard for the API project. I know, it's confusing, just to be clear clicking on this [http://i.imgur.com/NQ41S.png] brings me to this page [http://i.imgur.com/VrKpa.png]

Comment: @JohnIdol Wowzers. That's crazy. When I click on that link, I get the Google Cloud API Console's team members. Can you try, like, clearing cookies or caches or something?

Comment: Cleared cache etc. tried from another browser but I still get redirected to the permissions tab of what seems to be an AppEngine dashboard for the API project :(

Comment: Maybe it's something about the project? Can you try creating a new one and see what happens when you click on "Team"? I don't see how it could even know about App Engine, honestly.

Comment: I am very confused - every "cloud project" I create [http://i.imgur.com/SMVfs.png] leads me to an app-engine dashboard if I click on "team". Also noticed that every project I create like that comes up as an app-engine app in "My Applications". No idea what's going on.

Comment: @JohnIdol Crazy. How are you creating the projects? I'm doing it from the Google API Console, in that drop-down in your screenshot that reads "SC2 Quotes - BACKUP", under "Create...". It doesn't look anything like your screenshot when I do it. Do you have some special setup, like App Engine Premiere?

Comment: I created the project from that menu you suggested and it now shows me the correct team menu! I was creating the project from the google cloud storage "try it now" [https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage], which was probably stupid of me but still puzzling that it creates an AppEngine app. I am waiting to be able to create a bucket (takes a while) to give it another shot. Thanks!

Comment: OK - it worked! Thanks for you help. If you edit your question saying I should create the project from the apis console I will mark as answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your screenshot of the project creation step, it looks like you created your project via http://cloud.google.com/console. I suspect there's a problem with that path -- I'd suggest trying to create your project via http://code.google.com/apis/console and seeing if that works better. If you let me know the result of that experiment, I can file a bug report.

Comment: Indeed that's exactly what happened - I created the project from the cloud console instead of the apis console, and it automatically created an AppEngine project for me. If I create the project from the apis console everything works ok.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I just wrote a bug report.

Comment: Thank you for getting involved!